# PDOException There is no active transaction al hacer un test en laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, test

estoy haciendo un test en laravel 9, usando `RefreshDatabase` y primero intentando correr unos seeders que utilizo para importar datos y rellenar tablas de areas, area_groups y area_cities, todo esto funciona bien, pero quiero hacer test de rellenado de formularios livewire, y para eso necesito importar datos de dichas areas, pero obtengo el error

> PDOException
>
> There is no active transaction

si elimino el trait `RefreshDatabase` y dejo solamente el `InteractsWithDatabase` el test se ejecuta sin problemas, sin embargo, al finalizar el test, la base de datos no se vacía, y se supone que es para eso el `RefreshDatabase`

este es mi test

```
class UserProfileRegistrationTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    use InteractsWithDatabase;

    public function test_user_can_register_profile()
    {
        $this->seed();
        $user = User::factory()->create();

        $this->actingAs($user);
        Livewire::test(UserProfileInformationForm::class)
            ->set(['username' => 'tabimuse1',
                'occupation' => 'Doctor',
                'name' => 'tabimuse',
                'last_name' => 'last name',
                'self_introduction' => 'test self introduction',
                'gender' => 'Male',
                'area_city_id' => 67,
                'website' => 'https://www.facebook.com',
                'instagram_id' => 'tabimuse',
                ])
            ->call('save');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finalmente tuve que declarar una variable protegida antes de ejecutar los tests para que pueda hacer el seed

```
protected bool $seed = true;
```

con esto ya no es necesario utilizar el `InteractsWithDatabase` y utilizo solamente el `RefreshDatabase`